# List of events built into Angular 2?

Tags: angular2-directives

I find many tutorials on using events in Angular 2, but I cannot find a concrete, comprehensive list of events for reference. I would like a list sort of like the one provided for the [Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html), only for common events, such as (click), (focus), (mouseenter), etc.

Answer (score 1):

on angular 2, you are using native html events=>

[image]

```
(Are_you_looking_for_this_list)?
 "you need to check html specification pages":
 "I need more information to help you better :P";
```

For more information you can check mozila developer page >> [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: You answered it perfectly. I was just wondering where they get the events from.

Comment: from dom wich control by the browser and it is browser responsibility to emit them.

Comment: All the events that I tried here work fine except (load). Any idea why?